# Box Api - How to Get user details who commented a file

Tags: node.js, box-api, box, boxapiv2

I have a scenario in Box of commenting a file using Box Api. I have used Box api to add a comment. When displaying all the comments, it shows commented person name same for all comments.

How should I add a comment to differentiate who has commented it using Box API

Sample comment List:

```
{
    "type": "comment",
    "id": "1111",
    "is_reply_comment": false,
    "message": "Sample Comment 1",
    "created_by": {
      "type": "user",
      "id": "111",
      "name": "AAA",
      "login": "aaa@aaa.com"
    },
    "created_at": "2016-08-11T00:01:56-07:00",
    "item": {
      "id": "78110824178",
      "type": "file"
    },
    "modified_at": "2016-08-11T00:01:56-07:00"
}
{
    "type": "comment",
    "id": "2222",
    "is_reply_comment": false,
    "message": "Sample Comment 2",
    "created_by": {
      "type": "user",
      "id": "111",
      "name": "AAA",
      "login": "aaa@aaa.com"
    },
    "created_at": "2016-08-11T00:01:56-07:00",
    "item": {
      "id": "78110824178",
      "type": "file"
    },
    "modified_at": "2016-08-11T00:01:56-07:00"
}
```

Please help to add comments for different users

Answer (score 1):

To comment as a specific user, you can use the [As-User header](https://docs.box.com/reference#as-user-1). Here is an example:

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/comments \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" \
-H "As-User: USER_ID" \
-d '{"item": {"type": "file", "id": "FILE_ID"}, "message": "YOUR_MESSAGE"}' \
-X POST
```